# Sorting elements in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have models Topic and Post.

```
routes.rb

resources :topics do
  resources :posts
end
```

I want sort topics by created_at last post in this topics.

```
@topics = Topic.order(???)
```

Update:

```
Topic.includes(:posts).order("posts.created_at desc")
```

This code great work, but how order new topic without posts? New topic without posts must be first in top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing that there is a "has_many" relationship between Topic and Post, something like that should work:

```
Topic.includes(:posts).order("posts.created_at desc")
```

Be careful that having nested routes (as you have) does not means anything about the relationship between the models.

Comment: Error:
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'posts.created_at' in 'order clause': SELECT `topics`.* FROM `topics`  ORDER BY posts.created_at desc

Comment: yes, in model Topic 
    has_many :posts

in model Post
    belongs_to :topic

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way I prefer using

```
Topic.includes(:posts).merge(Post.order(created_at: :desc))
```

And if you have scopes that would be better

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :ordered_by_creation, -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
end
```

The query would become

```
Topic.includes(:posts).merge(Post.ordered_by_creation)
```